# Problema substituição de caracteres acentuados

Tags: php, acentuação, preg-replace

A função `preg_replace` não está se comportando da maneira que eu previa. Ao executar o código `$string = preg_replace("/[ÁÀÂÃÄáàâãä]/", "a", $string);` o que recebo de retorno é uma string cheia de "a"s. Se a string tem "ÁÀÂÃÄáàâãäÍÌíì" a resposta do `preg_replace` é "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaiaiaiai". Sabem me explicar porque isso acontece? E qual a melhor maneira de fazer essa substituição?

Comment: Use a flag `u` na regex (logo deopis da segunda barra): `preg_replace("/[ÁÀÂÃÄáàâãä]/u", "a", $string)`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o **incov** para o fazer:

```
preg_replace('/[^a-z]/i', '', iconv("UTF-8", "US-ASCII//TRANSLIT", $string))
```

Se entendi bem o seu problema, esta deve ser a resolução.